# can anyone help explain the orbot log

Tags: orbot, android

[image]

im not sure what this means exactly.  I have an idea and have asked around but I'd like to get more input

Answer (score 1):

Those "unused DT entry" messages mean that either your app crashes or it generates lots of error messages. Probably Tor was cross-compiled with wrong or deprecated compilation flags. In my opinion the best is to [enter a bug report](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/query?status=accepted&status=assigned&status=needs_information&status=needs_review&status=needs_revision&status=new&status=reopened&component=Applications%2FOrbot&group=type&col=id&col=summary&col=component&col=status&col=type&col=priority&col=milestone&col=points&report=14&order=priority).

This [answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41900551/391761) has more details about the message.